How to use Dependabot with private packages in GitLab
https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/configuring-access-to-private-registries-for-dependabot
version: 2
registries:
  gradle-artifactory:
    type: maven-repository
    url: https://acme.jfrog.io/artifactory/my-gradle-registry
    username: octocat
    password: glpat-my-token
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "maven"
    directory: "/"
    registries: "*"
    schedule:
      interval: "monthly"

I know we can set gitlab token like above and it works.
But how can I hide the access token? Or is there another way to workaround?
password: ${access_token}

${} doesn't work for me.
